# Regarding Portal User

Tags: user, portal, new

**How to get a mail,when new portal user is created, with the help of customer portal settings** in customization
not coding

Comment: Who needs to get the email? The new user? Another Salesforce user?

Comment: go on below link.https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customer_portal_enabling_features_settings.htm&language=en

Comment: Administrator did not getting a mail when new portal user is created

Answer (score 0):

**under Email Notification Settings:
Change Owner to Portal User Template:New User Login Information(Sample)**